# Django & Postgres: Unique Constraint not enforced? "Space" encoding?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    ...
```

As you can see, "my_field" must be unique. Before creating a new object I run

```
field_value: str = 'test 12/9'
try:
    o = MyModel.objects.get(my_field=field_value)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    o = MyModel()
...
```

to check if an object with the unique `field_value` exists. So far so good.
Now I realised that I do have hundrets of "duplicate" values in `my_field`.

Here are the copied exact values from django admin:

1. `2 StR 46/15`
2. `2 StR 46/15`

As you can see, they seem to be the same. But if I copy one value to the other field in django admin and try to save it, it fails due to an object already existing with this 'my_field'. But when saving each object itself, it does not fail.

I used several tools to compare the strings, I am incapable to find a diffrence.

Is there a way, that django or postgres is converting these strings somewhere so they are not the same anymore? Am I missing anything?

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**

I just checked the binary representation of my strings and it seems the spaces are decoded diffrent.

For the 1st one SPACE is: "`10100000`"

For the 2nd one SPACE is: "`100000`"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you call `o.save()` in your except block? When simply calling `MyModel()` you just create a new instance of the object in-memory, it's not automatically backed by a row in the database, only calling `.save()` on it does so and should validate any integrity checks (e.g. not duplicates) as expected. Try the following:

```
field_value: str = 'test 12/9'
o, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(my_field=field_value)
# use your object now, it's in-memory and backed by a row in the database
```

Comment: Thanks for your thought! Yes sure that is done below. I just wanted to show that I double check the unique constraint if you will. However if I would have forgotten it, postgres should squark due to the unique constraint. However the fields seem to be unique, only that i cant see any diffrence :/